# Javascript object with array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

[image: JSON Data]

My code so far:

```
    recentTracks.items.map(item => {
        res.push({
            trackName: item.track.name,
            artistNames: item.track.artists.map(artist=>
                {
                    console.log(artist.name);
                    return // not sure what to do here
                })
        })
    })
```

res is the object and for each artist.name, I want to push it into the array but I'm not sure how.

Comment: recentTracks.items.map(item => {
    res.push({
        trackName: item.track.name,
        artistNames: item.track.artists.map(artist => artist.name)
    })
})


This should do the trick

Comment: [**Please do not upload images of text (code/input/output/errors, or otherwise) on Stack Overflow**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be close there. Hard to tell what's inside `item.track.artists`, but let's assume there is a `name` attribute that stores the artist's name. Then do this:

```
    const res = [];
    recentTracks.items.map(item => {
        res.push({
            trackName: item.track.name,
            artistNames: item.track.artists.map(artist => artist.name)
        })
    })
```

You can even shorten it a little further:

```
const res = recentTracks.items.map(item => {
        return {
            trackName: item.track.name,
            artistNames: item.track.artists.map(artist => artist.name)
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    recentTracks.items.map(item => {
    res.push({
        trackName: item.track.name,
        artistNames: item.track.artists.map(artist => artist.name)
    })
})
```

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)).

Comment: question was just asked what to return instead of console.log..so updated that part of code... i usually add comment or explanation where it actually required.

Comment: "*i usually add comment or explanation where it actually required*" -- well that's fine, but as explained in the post I linked "*While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.*" The point here is that its not immediately obvious what has changed in the code, or why its changed. A line or two to explain that would be helpful, and provide more value for future users as well.

Comment: For some context, I came across this post while doing the [Low Quality Posts reviews](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/28332820); code-only answers tend to end up in that queue.